# Website fade when loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my website to fade out when you access the website, I've added this script to the head:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
         $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
      })
   </script>
```

and then added a div in my body:

```
 <div class="loader"></div>
```

But it isn't working and I can't find why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ready` event instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/s5g94h68/

Comment: thanks, is there any way to test fadeIn in local? It doesn't work, but fadeOut does.

Comment: Of course, see here https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/s5g94h68/1/. Note the `display: none` should be applied to work with `fadeIn`.